# Insert newline in html format using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the string value that has `&#10;`. I want replace this with `\n`. and when I convert it to html format after each line comes to another line. But this not work.

```
$StdOut = 'total 40&#10;drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:55 .&#10;drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:54 ..&#10;-rw------- 1 root root &#32; &#32;0 Jun 16 14:55 cimserver_start.lock&#10;srwxrwxrwx 1 root root &#32; &#32;0
```

Jun 16 14:55 cim.socket
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 16 17:58 localauth
-rw------- 1 root root    6 Jun 16 14:55 scx-cimd.pid
'

```
$CResult = $StdOut -replace "&#10;", "\n"
```

After using `Convert-html` I have the text like this :

```
'total 40\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:55 .\ndrwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:54 ..\n-rw------- 1 root root &#32; &#32;0 Jun 16 14:55 cimserver_start.lock\nsrwxrwxrwx 1 root root &#32; &#32;0 Jun 16 14:55
 cim.socket\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 16 17:58 localauth\n-rw------- 1 root root &#32; &#32;6 Jun 16 14:55 scx-cimd.pid\n
```

'

How can I do this?

Comment: `\ ` is not a character escape sequence in PowerShell, you should use a backtick instead: `"\`n"`

Answer (score 2):

The approach Mathias mentions works fine for newlines.  But if you have (or could have) other entity refs then I would use the HtmlDecode method e.g.

```
Add-Assembly System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($StdOut)
```

Outputs:

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:54 ..
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Jun 16 14:55 cimserver_start.lock
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-Assembly System.Web
Add-Assembly : The term 'Add-Assembly' is not recognized as the name of a   
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if 

a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Assembly System.Web
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Assembly:String) [],   
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web')
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($StdOut)
```

Gives me

```
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 16 14:54 ..
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Jun 16 14:55 cimserver_start.lock
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0
```